# Clarification for terminology on filepaths

Tags: python, path, naming-conventions, filenames

I know how to extract the parts of a path I need using `os.path.listdir` or `os.path.basename.` For better variable and method naming I would like to know what the differences are in terms of terminology in the following:

```
   a =  C:\...\Desktop\some_folder\my_file.txt
   b =  C:\...\Desktop\some_folder\my_file
   c = C:\...\Desktop\some_folder\
   d = my_file.txt
```

If you had to have all four in your code for some reason what would you call them as variables?

Comment: ```a``` would be ```current_path```, ```c``` would be ```parent_path```, ```d``` would be ```current_file```. Wouldn't use ```b``` though, without specifying filetype

Comment: I have a scenario where I get images from one folder, with a .bmp extension, but need to save the image name without extension to use it as a filename for the results taken from testing with that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *a* is a *file path*
2. *b* is a *file path sans suffix*
3. *c* is a *directory path*
4. *d* is a *filename*